# Why does functional interface with void return-type method accept any return-type method?

Tags: java, void, functional-interface

We have this code:

```
public class Test {
    public static Object foo() {
        System.out.println("Foo");
        return new Object();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        J j = Test::foo;
        j.m();
    }

}
interface J {
    void m();
}
```

And this code will work. The crucial line is

```
J j = Test::foo;
```

Although `interface J` declares it has a `void` function, `Test::foo` returns an `Object`.

While we can't override method while implementing interface (which is obvious).
This works only when interface's method is `void`, otherwise the code won't be compiled. Could someone tell why does this work in the way it works? :D

Comment: lambda is just a syntactic sugar, a return statement is added when the return type is other than `void`. If the return isn't void and the type is mismatched then compiler complains.

Comment: There's probably a great technical explanation for this, but basically it's syntactic sugar. You can always ignore a return value (from `foo()`), but you can't make one up, so it doesn't work the other way around (`foo()` being `void` and `m()` having a return type).

Comment: I think you got your answer: *a return statement is added when the return type is other than `void`*.

Comment: I think it is documented at [JLS 15.13.2. Type of a Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2) - relevant text: "...A method reference expression is congruent with a function type if...The result of the function type is void..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Although `interface J` declares it has a `void` function, `Test::foo` returns an `Object`.

It's inaccurate to say that `Test::foo` returns something. In different contexts, it could mean different things.

```
Supplier<Object>  a = Test::foo;
J                 b = Test::foo;
Runnable          c = Test::foo;
```

It's more accurate to say that `Test::foo` can represent [a target type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html) [the functional method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html) of which returns either `void` or `Object`.

It's an example of [expression statement (jls-14.8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8).

> If the target type's function type has a `void` return, then the lambda body is either **a statement expression** ([§14.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8)) or a void-compatible block ([§15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2)).
>   ...
>   An expression statement is executed by evaluating the expression; if the expression has a value, **the value is discarded.**

Comment: An expression statement means a statement which is an expression followed by a semicolon, like the expression `a.foo()` could be written as a statement `a.foo();`. So a method reference expression `Test::foo` is not an expression statement. (It is also not a lambda.)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what exactly is confusing you so here is some other way how you can look at your example.

---

```
J j = Test::foo;
```

can be rewritten as

```
J j = () -> Test.foo();
```

since it provides body to `m()` method from `J` functional interface and that method doesn't require any arguments (which is why it starts with `() ->`).

But that can be seen as shorter version of

```
J j = new J(){
    public void m(){
        Test.foo(); //correct despite `foo` returning value    
    }
};
```

which is correct, because Java allows us to ignore returned value of called method like in case of [`List#add(E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#add(E)) which returns `boolean` value, but we still are allowed to write code like `list.add(1)` without having to handle returned value.

Comment: But if I edit the interface method and make it return `int`, for example, I am able to cast `foo()` to `int`, so does lambda automatically make the line `J j = () -> (int) Test.foo();` something like `J j = () -> return (int) Test.foo();`? Ignore that ClassCastException

Comment: If you would need to explicitly cast value in standard anonymous class then you would most likely need to also cast it in lambda, which would prevent you from rewriting it as method reference. In case you described you can't have `()->Test.foo();` and you need to cast it to `int` like you've shown `J j = () -> (int) Test.foo();` (and no - it will not be done automatically).